# C string literal from a Nim compiler

Tags: c, nim-lang

If I read the generated C code from "Hello World!" in Nim, I see this line

`STRING_LITERAL(TM_xLHv575t3PG1lB5wK05Xqg_2, "Hello world!", 12);`

How is the sequence `TM_xLHv575t3PG1lB5wK05Xqg_2` created? Is the Nim compiler actually generating this name from itself, or does it use pre-defined names for variables when translating to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generating the names using md5 hash of a module info as a base. The process is mostly confined to the `compiler/cgen.nim` file.

The actual name comes from here: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/d5da450100f35008df06ecf812f1eeabda05d285/compiler/cgen.nim#L233

The components of the name are derived from the module parameters here: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/d5da450100f35008df06ecf812f1eeabda05d285/compiler/cgen.nim#L1468